Is it possible to change the color of label inside Picker?
I have an app and I want to implement an option to change the app's accent color but only with a certain selection of colors and I want them inside of a picker with a label with a circle of each color option's color
I've tried using a picker inside of a menu (because I want the label to not have the image) and applying .foregroundStyle, .tint and .background with no result and I'm starting to think it is not possible or not easy to do so. Here is my current code. Thanks.
Menu {
  Picker("", selection: vm.$selectedColor) {
    ForEach(colorOptions.allCases) { option in
      Label(option.rawValue.capitalized, systemImage: "circle.fill")
        .foregroundColor(option.color)
        .tag(option)
    }
  }
}  label: {
    Text("Select color")
}

ColorOptions:
enum colorOptions: String, CaseIterable, Identifiable {
  
  var id: String { self.rawValue }
  
  case indigo
  case red
  case green
  case blue
  case yellow
  case orange
  case purple
  
  var color: Color {
    switch self {
    case .indigo: return .indigo
    case .red: return .red
    case .green: return .green
    case .blue: return .blue
    case .yellow: return .yellow
    case .orange: return .orange
    case .purple: return .purple
    }
  }
}

Note that these are not the colors i want to use those were for testing the picker

You cannot change the color of the label title. However, you can at least show a color swab next to the title. See SwiftUI Picker issue with Rectangle() instead of Text()

As far as I know, menus and pickers will ignore any styling like color, font, etc.
For maximum control, you will need to build your own menu. I started working on one a while back, but it's really just the core structure right now.
Here's the code:
import SwiftUI

enum pickerColor: String, CaseIterable, Identifiable {
    
    var id: String { self.rawValue }
    
    case indigo
    case red
    case green
    case blue
    case yellow
    case orange
    case purple
    
    var color: Color {
        switch self {
            case .indigo: return .indigo
            case .red: return .red
            case .green: return .green
            case .blue: return .blue
            case .yellow: return .yellow
            case .orange: return .orange
            case .purple: return .purple
        }
    }
}

struct PickerMenuColor: View {
    
    //State values
    @State private var showMenu = false
    @State private var selectedColor: pickerColor = .indigo

    //Body
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack {
            
            //Button that opens the menu
            Button {
                showMenu.toggle() //this can also be wrapped in withAnimation {showMenu.toggle()}
            } label: {
                //Button label
                HStack {
                    Text("\(selectedColor.rawValue.capitalized)")
                    
                    //Label chevron - comment out if picker style icon not needed
                    Image(systemName: "chevron.up.chevron.down")
                        .font(.system(size: 13))
                }
                //Label color
                .foregroundStyle(selectedColor.color)
            }
            .overlay(alignment: .bottom) {
                if showMenu {
                    VStack(spacing: 5) {
                        
                        //Make cases into an array for having access to an index
                        let pickerColorsArray = Array(pickerColor.allCases.enumerated())
                        
                        //Menu loop
                        ForEach(pickerColorsArray, id: \.element ) { index, color in
                            
                            //Option row
                            Button {
                                withAnimation {
                                    selectedColor = color
                                    showMenu.toggle() //comment this out if you want menu to remain open after making a selection
                                }
                                
                            } label : {
                                //Option label
                                VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 5) {
                                    HStack {
                                        Label {
                                            Text("\(color.rawValue.capitalized)")
                                        } icon: {
                                            Image(systemName: selectedColor == color ? "checkmark" : "circle")
                                                .font(.system(size: 12))
                                                .opacity(color == selectedColor ? 1 : 0)
                                        }
                                        
                                        //Horizontal spacing
                                        Spacer()
                                        
                                        //Colored circle icon
                                        Image(systemName: "circle.fill")
                                            .foregroundStyle(color.color)
                                    }
                                    
                                    //Row padding
                                    .padding(.horizontal)
                                    .padding(.vertical, 5)
                                    
                                    //Add divider after each row except for the last row
                                    if index != pickerColorsArray.count - 1 {
                                        Divider()
                                            .frame(height: 5)
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            //Option row text color (button tint)
                            .tint(.black)
                        }
                    }
                    //Menu width
                    .frame(width: 200) //use .fixedSize() instead of .frame if custom width not needed
                    
                    //Menu top and bottom padding
                    .padding(.vertical, 10)
                    
                    //Menu background
                    .background(.thinMaterial, in: RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20))
                    
                    //Menu position (customize as needed, additional logic may be required here)
                    .offset(y: -30)
                    
                    //Menu shadow
                    .shadow(color: .black.opacity(0.2) , radius: 70)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    PickerMenuColor()
}


Note: When posting code for questions, make sure it's complete and reproducible so it can be copied and pasted without the need for further guesses and additions.
